# How to redirect to HTTPS from Angular+Node app hosted in Heroku from a subdomain?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, swagger-node-express

Been struggling with this for a couple of day now.
I have an Angular 9 app, a subdomain (subdomain.side.com) and a Heroku app running Nodejs server.
Heroku app has SSL and is connected correctly to the domain panel via DNS, also heroku is running a simple server to start the app.

**Problem**

I want to redirect user to the HTTPS of my subdomain, for instance if user types http://subdomain.side.com it will be redirected to the HTTPS site (https://subdomain.side.com).

Attempts

1. Added the .htaccess file. Also added it to the prod folder as well.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

2. Configures with a lot of different setups the server.js file the latest is:

> ```
> const express = require('express');
> const compression = require('compression');
> const path = require('path');
> const app = express();
> app.use(compression());
> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/APP'));
>
> function ensureSecure(req, res, next) {
>   if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
>     return next();
>   }
>   res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
> }
>
> app.all('*', ensureSecure);
> app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
>   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/APP/index.html'));
> });
> app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but a workaround if somebody is struggling with the same issue.
I added a guard to the root route checking if the page is not HTTPS then redirect it to HTTPS, not ideal but...

```
  if (location.protocol === 'http:') {
      window.location.href = location.href.replace('http', 'https');
   }
```